# Who are these characters?

Tags: merchandise

I received 2 anime figure at a yard sale. Can anyone help me identify who they are.

Thanks a bunch

[image]

[image]

Comment: the bottom one is Mari from the Neon Genesis Evangelion Reboot movies. not sure of the top one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are Asahina Mikuru from *The Melancholy of Haruhi Suzumiya*:

[image: Asahina Mikuru]

and Mari Makinami Illustrious from *Evangelion 2.0: You Can (Not) Advance*:

[image: Mari Makinami Illustrious]